# Need to Integrate a SMS gateway to my application provided by third party solution,

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

i am new to laravel 5.3 i need to integration a SMS gateway to my application, i have already purchased SMS credit from the third party solution provides, since they don't have package for laravel i have to include the library class manually, can anyone help me with this

This is the code i need to include in the laravel controller. how to include   the external class sendsms.php in the controller..

```
<?php 
include 'sendsms.php';
$sendsms=new sendsms("http://api-alerts.solutionsinfini.com/v3/",'sms'
                      , "11XXXXXXXXXXX78", "SIXXXX");
$sendsms->send_sms("99XXXXXXXX", "message", 'http://www.yourdomainname.domain/yourdlrpage&custom=XX', 'xml');
$sendsms->schedule_sms("99XXXXXXXX", "message"
                     , "http://www.yourdomainname.domain/yourdlrpage&custom=XX", 'xml',
                      'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM PM/AM');
$sendsms->unicode_sms("99XXXXXXXX","unicode message",
                      "http://www.yourdomainname.domain/yourdlrpage&custom=XX",'xml','1');
$sendsms->messagedelivery_status("99XXXXXX-X");
$sendsms->groupdelivery_status("99XXXXXX");

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Recommended way to solve your problem will be to write a package for SMS gateway. Have a look at this link https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/packages

If you don't want to write and publish a package for your SMS gateway then you will need at least:

1. Copy the sendsms.php file into your laravel project
2. Namespace it appropriately
3. Include into your controller by "use" statement. for example "use  Packages/Sendsms"

Comment: Yes, I have create a folder inside app directory as an librarypackage. included sendsms.php class file, in that file at the top i have included  namespace as "App\libaraypackage;" and in the controller i have used it as use "App\librarypackage\sendsms;" but i run the controller i am getting an error as "Class 'App\Http\Controllers\sendsms' not found "

Comment: In your use statement pls try use App\librarypackage\sendsms as sendsms